# Implement 'Foldable' on NonEmpty

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

Given:

```
data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty a (Array a)
```

I completed the following exercise from [PureScript by Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read):

> Write a Foldable instance for NonEmpty. Hint: reuse the Foldable instance for arrays.

```
instance foldableNonEmpty :: Foldable NonEmpty where
  foldr f acc (NonEmpty a as) = foldr f (f a acc) as
  foldl f acc nonEmpty        = foldr (flip f) acc nonEmpty
  foldMap f (NonEmpty a as)   = f a <> (foldMap f as)
```

Please critique my implementation. Can I do better?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Given that `foldr` is right-associative, your implementation is incorrect. Intuitively, `foldr` will recurse down a structure until it bottoms out *and then* will it start accumulating the result by going back up. So, this version would be more appropriate:

```
foldr f acc (NonEmpty a as) = f a (foldr f acc as)
```

In fact your version is a correct `foldl`:

```
foldl f acc (NonEmpty a as) = foldl f (f acc a) as
```

I think your version of `foldMap` is fine given the associativity of the monoidal operation.